# CORREL function not showing result

Tags: excel, function, correlation

I am using excel and trying to calculate the correlation coefficient with CORREL function. The result I get is #VALUE!. How could I fix it? Thank you in advance.

[image]

The function i used was CORREL(A1:A13, B1:B13). The indexes are random

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 21,1189 | 21,44273333 |
| 21,16266667 | 21,39306667 |
| 21,17916667 | 21,3 |
| 21,11473333 | 21,12776667 |
| 21,00103333 | 20,86996667 |
| 20,8431 | 20,53136667 |
| 20,6457 | 20,14513333 |
| 20,40923333 | 19,73653333 |
| 20,14266667 | 19,32443333 |
| 19,9243 | 18,9355 |
| 19,75976667 | 18,6063 |
| 19,66686667 | 18,38103333 |
| 19,6237 | 18,2528 |
| 19,6284 | 18,21636667 |
| 19,68933333 | 18,2881 |

Comment: Are `A1` and `B1` the headers X and Y?

Comment: If you are getting #value then most likely your "numbers" at stored as text and not true numbers.

Comment: @BigBen X and Y are the headers. A1 and B1 are the first elements of each data set.

Comment: Then you're dealing with numbers stored as text as @ScottCraner mentioned.

Comment: Alright so if I format my data as numbers it should work?

Comment: My data is stored as numbers though

Comment: Format does not change the underlying value, if the value is text then changing the format will not change anything.  The formula works with the data you gave.  So something is amiss on your sheet and the data to which it refers.

Comment: @ScottCraner I see. Thanks a lot.